# Powershell rename-item using RegEx for filename irregular pattern

Tags: powershell, regex

I have filenames in a directory that have different beginning strings of characters that I wish to strip out and leave just the alpha characters + file extension:

[**example**]

1-09. But Not for Me.mp3
1-11. Summertime.mp3
1-12. My Funny Valentine.mp3
13. Indiana (Back Home Again in Indiana).mp3
2-02 I Love You.mp3
2-05 You'd Be So Nice To Come Home To.mp3
2-11. A Foggy Day.mp3

The only pattern I see is that the RegEx should strip out all the characters up to the FIRST alpha character.

[**desired output**]

But Not for Me.mp3
Summertime.mp3
My Funny Valentine.mp3
Indiana (Back Home Again in Indiana).mp3
I Love You.mp3
You'd Be So Nice To Come Home To.mp3
A Foggy Day.mp3

What would the Powershell look like to accomplish this?

I thought something along these lines but I don't know RegEx well enough to accomplish my goal.

`foreach ($file in (get-childitem *.mp3).name) { Rename-Item $file ($file -replace '^[^-]*-\s*') }`

thanks

Comment: Check out regex101.com there you can test your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use: `^\d+(?:-\d+)?\.?`  and replace with nothing.

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
    (?:         # non capture group
        -           # hyphen
        \d+         # 1 or more digits
    )?          # end group, optional
    \.?         # optional dot
                # a space
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/4r430C/1)

Comment: Hello, I tested that RegEx in Notepad++ it but it only selects the numerical portion of the line, not the characters up to the first Alpha character

Comment: @JeffTaylor: Have you put a space at the end of the regex? As it's describe in my answer. I also tested in Notepad++ and it works fine, at least for the examples given.

Comment: good catch. I did add one whitespace and that does pickup a few more lines but still not picking up a "-" or additional whitespace leading up to the first alpha character.

Comment: @JeffTaylor: Could you give some examples that don't work? Probably change the last space with `[- ]*`

Comment: Yes @Toto that worked perfectly. Thanks for hanging in there to help out.

This was my final one-liner:

`foreach ($file in (get-childitem *.mp3).name) { Rename-Item $file ($file -replace '^\d+(?:-\d+)?\.?[- ]*')}`